# Open custom app by URL from browser's address bar

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I writed a simple Android application and added a intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.somesite.com" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Okay. Now, when I click by link from another application (like GMail) i see a dialog: choose application for run: MyApp or Browser.

But when I type this URL in browser's address bar it just open a site.

How can set up my app like a Google Play, Google+?  (When I type a http://play.google.com/ - i see a dialog Google Play App or Browser)

Comment: @varunbhardwaj sorry but I don't remember. It was a year ago and I have not a source code of this app.